# DateFormatter parse String to Date gives wrong format

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I have the following piece of code:

```
System.out.println(array[9]);
Date d = df.parse(array[9]);
System.out.println(d.toString());
```

and the result of this looks like the following:

> 01.01.2017
>
> Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2017

My DateFormatter:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy",Locale.GERMANY);
```

So my question is now why I get the wrong format.
First result is a string, which I must convert to date.
But I got the wrong format, not the German one (dd.MM.yyyy).

What's wrong?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you should use `df.format(d)` if you plan to convert `Date` to `String`. The default `Date.toString()` method will use the predefined format which you can't control.

Comment: Thanks. But i must convert from String to date

Comment: You already converted from `String` to `Date` with `df.parse()`. `Date` is a placeholder. It's unrelated to a display format. If you plan to display the placeholder in specific format you must use `df.format()` method.